# Custom plugin doent work RHEL

Tags: bash, nagios

I have successfully created a bash script, that is executable from nagios user. The problem is that this script works fine from Linux command line, but it's return the unknown status if runned by nagios ( returned in web GUI).

I have placed script in nagios server:
loc:  `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/`

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
rootUsage=$(du -s /root | cut -d "/" -f1)
output=$(du -s /root | cut -d "/" -f1)
if(($rootUsage<= 204800));then
echo "OK. root storage is : $output :"
exit 0
elif((204800<$rootUsage) && ($rootUsage<211111)); then
echo "WARNING. root storage is : $output"
exit 1
elif(($rootUsage >= 211111));then
echo "CRITICAL. root storage is : $output"
exit 2
else
echo "UNKNOWN. root storage given value : $rootUsage"
exit 3
fi
```

---

Command creation:

## 'check_root_space' command definition

```
define command{
 command_name    check_root_space
 command_line    $USER1$/check_root_space
 }
```

---

Service creation:

```
define service{
use                     generic-service
host_name               NagiosLinuxClient
service_description     Monitor Root Usage
check_command           check_nrpe!check_root_space
}
```

---

Ngios  clinet end:

Same bash script is placed in `/usr/local/nagios/libexe/`  directory

And coomand is configured in nagios, cfg file

```
command[chech_root_space]=/usr/local/nagios/libexe/check_root_space
```

---

When I tried to execute plugin from nagios server using following command

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexe/check_nrpe -H <ip addressofclient> -c check_root_space
```

Final output:

```
NRPE: Command 'check_root_space' not defined
```

Comment: As which user is this executed?

Comment: i have executed with root and also using nagios user

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: script works fine, 
script output : 
     OK. root storage is : 118M  :

Comment: is this line `command[chech_root_space]=/usr/local/nagios/libexe/check_root_space` in NRPE config? Are you restarted NRPE deamon after that?

Comment: yes it is present in 'client' nrpe.cfg and i have restarted 'xinetd' service after that